# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row<br />Error No: 1242 in opencart

Tags: exception, mysqli, opencart

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row
Error No: 1242
SELECT o.order_id, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, (SELECT os.name FROM ocny_order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '1') AS order_status,(SELECT os.name FROM ocny_order_product os WHERE os.order_id = o.order_id) AS name, o.shipping_code, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value,telephone AS telephone,shipping_address_1 AS shipping_address_1,shipping_city AS shipping_city, o.date_added, o.date_modified FROM `ocny_order` o WHERE (o.order_status_id = '2') ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT 0,20'

Comment: I don't see a question here. What can we help you with? Do you want to know what the error message means? Which subquery has the problem? How to rewrite your query to work around this problem?

Comment: "(SELECT os.name FROM ocny_order_product"  just need to change os.name in this query to GROUP_CONCAT(os.name) . worked perfectly ...thanks @cez for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your subselects to generate a column is returning more than one row. You either need to use LIMIT 1 to force a single row to be returned, or use GROUP_CONCAT in the subselect to equally return a single row.

e.g.

```
SELECT os.name FROM ocny_order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '1' LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(os.name) FROM ocny_order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '1')
```

Comment: "(SELECT os.name FROM ocny_order_product"  just need to change os.name in this query to GROUP_CONCAT(os.name) . worked perfectly ...thanks @cez for the help